# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,System.Type]' while attempting to activate App

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2022, maui

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am attempting to run a .NET MAUI program, however, I am getting the following error:
`` Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,System.Type]' while attempting to activate 'App'. ``

Here's where the error seems to be happening:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Models;

namespace Droid
{
    [Application(Label = "[insert name here]", Icon = "@drawable/logo")]
    public class Application: MauiApplication
    {
        public Application(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

        protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate(); <-Error happens here.
        }
    }
}
```

While stepping through the app, it also runs the CreateMauiApp function here:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Maui.Hosting;

namespace Commander
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder.UseMauiApp<App>();
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant parts of the App class:

```
namespace Commander
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App(Dictionary<Type, Type> platformDependecies)
        {
        }
```

Comment: I did a test on my side, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post a basic demo so that I can try to reproduce this problem on my side?

Comment: What do you mean by a basic demo?  Apologies for my lack of experience in mobile development.

Comment: I mean you can create a simple app and upload it to github ,then share link here so that we can try could reproduce this problem. For more information, check: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks!  I think I figured out what the issue is (for those interested to know, UseMauiApp needs a constructor for your app class without any arguments), but I'll keep your link in mind for future issues!

Comment: Congrats. And thanks for your support and feedback.  Have a nice day. :)